# Trying to hide button if next step does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make the button "next" disappear if there is no next step. I have tried the following and got stuck here. I have tasks with related steps using ForeignKey.

I think my method is not working because the PK is not always starting at 1. example task one have steps pk 1,2,3. Task two have steps pk 4,5,6.

Is it possible to make the PK always be 1,2,3 for each task? Then this might work? Or is there a better solution?

views.py

```
def step_detail(request, task_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, task_id=task_pk, pk=step_pk)
    next_step_pk = step_pk + 1
    next_step = Step.objects.filter(pk=next_step_pk)
    if next_step.count() == 0:
        next_step_pk = None

    return render(request, 'dailytask/step_detail.html', {'step': step,
                                                          'next_step_pk': next_step_pk})
```

models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORIES, default="traffic")
    done_message = models.TextField(null=True, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    user_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    step_number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

step_detail.html

I want this button to hide when there are no more steps in the task.

```
{% if next_step_pk %}
    <a href="{% url 'step' task_pk=step.task.pk step_pk=next_step_pk %}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" style="background-color:rgba(0,123,255,0);margin-bottom:0px;">Next Step</button>
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
path('<int:task_pk>/<int:step_pk>/', views.step_detail, name='step'),
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate `pk`s in any model. I would use the `order` field for that purpose. Make sure to add a `unique_together = ('task', 'order')` index under `Meta` and you are all set.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I add it?

Comment: It is a `Meta` option: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: I am not sure what I need to do after adding the unique Meta, should I change anything in the view and html template?

Comment: If you add the meta, it will require that the order field and task field be unique for every row. So that each step for task N will only have 1 step with an order 1. 
IF you do that method you want to change your url logic so you're using the order value rather than the PK to create the path. And you'll loopup the next step by lookup up the PK of the related field, task and order +1.

Comment: Thank you. 
I tried the following:
path('<int:task_pk>/<int:order>/', views.step_detail, name='step'),

I am not sure what to do, it's not working.

task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="steps")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', ]
        unique_together = ("task", "order")

Comment: It's hard to read unformatted code. Best to just a gjst or pastebin or edit your question.  What does your view look like now? Because if you're using the order as the key to get it, you also need to update the get call to get the current step.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the PK to find the next step isn't going to work. The PK isn't related to the task.
Imagine that you have two tasks with 3 steps, then you add a new step to the first task.
That would mean the first task would have 4 steps with pks of 1,2,3 and 7.

You have a relation between task and step. Set up a related name in the foreignkeyField.
`task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="steps")`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/

Then when doing the lookup you can do such:

`next_steps = step.task.steps.filter(order__gt=step.order)`
This will do a lookup in the database for all steps for that task, which have an order number greater than step.order. I might have the syntax wrong, but I think I got it correct, if it doens't work do some reading here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/

Then you can call `next_steps.count()` and `next_steps[0]` to get the next step. 
Now that you have a working method to get the next step, you should be able to figure out a way to toggle the button.